# Swift function somehow downloads an image that no longer exists

Tags: php, ios, swift, uiimage, nsurlsession

I'm downloading an image from a link and setting it to a UIImageView using a custom function. I've updated the image on my server while the image path remains the same. However, when I call the function, it somehow downloads the old image even though that image path has a new updated image. When I simply type in the image path on Google it comes up with the correct, updated image. I even tried deleting the image and the function still downloaded that old one. How can this be possible?!

My function is an extension of UIImageView:

```
func downloadImageFrom(link: String) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask( with URL(string:link)!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            if let data = data { self.image = UIImage(data: data) }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

And is called like this: `imageView.downloadImageFrom(link: "(example link)")`

Comment: You should have a look at the cache settings you are using.

Comment: Do you mean on the server, or say UserDefaults?

Comment: Along with that, delete the app from the device/simulator and reinstall. This sort of thing happens if you are talking a launch screen.

Comment: @Legatro on the device. `UserDefaults` have nothing to do with cache, but `URLSession` has a default cache policy for instance.